# using ols from statsmodels.formula.api - how to remove constant term?

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels, patsy

I'm following this first example in `statsmodels` tutorial:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/

How do I specify not to use constant term for linear fit in ols?

```
# Fit regression model (using the natural log of one of the regressors)
results = smf.ols('Lottery ~ Literacy + np.log(Pop1831)', data=dat).fit()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [shown here in the section on Operators](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html), you can use "-1" in the formula string to remove an intercept term:

```
results = smf.ols('Lottery ~ Literacy + np.log(Pop1831) - 1', data=dat).fit()
```

Comment: Another option is to add zero to the formula.